# twitter's user search api:- search using email id

Tags: api

I am working on a requirement where I need to fetch user profile from various social media sites. For example, I can use the twitter's user search api to fetch user profile using the user name. But i have only email address and want to fetch user profile data from twitter using email address. I found out that twitter's api does not support user search based on email address. Similarly facebook API also does not support user profile search based on email ID. Is there any other way to fetch the user profile data from these websites using email Id's?